# Gmail app on iPhone doesn't launch App Store on email redirects

Tags: ios, email, app-store, gmail

I'm sending emails to people invited by a user with a link to my app in the App Store, ie.

```
http://itunes.apple.com/app/id1234567890
```

It opens the App Store when tapped in the Mail app, but not in the Gmail app. Any ideas to get around this (or show something nicer than a bunch of XML, which is what appears when tapping the link in Gmail)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the link of the style

```
http://itunes.com/apps/YOUR_APP_NAME_GOES_HERE
```